Is the Fitting subgroup compatible with surjective homomorphisms?
If $G$ is a group, its Fitting subgroup $F_G$ is generated by all normal nilpotent subgroups of $G$. By the Fitting Lemma, it is equal to the union of the normal nilpotent subgroups. If $G$ is finite then $F_G$ is also nilpotent but that doesn't hold in general.
I have two related questions that I couldn't find an answer for in the literature (maybe because it is too easy), also not by myself since I have almost no knowledge about concrete computations of the Fitting subgroup.
First question: I have read here that we have $\varphi(F_G) = F_G$ for every surjective homomorphism $\varphi : G \to G$. What is a reference for this result? Does it also hold when $G$ is infinite? (The literature is mostly concerned with finite groups, for which the claim is trivial.)
Second question: If $\varphi : G \to H$ is any surjective homomorphism, I have checked $\varphi(F_G) \subseteq F_H$, but I assume $\varphi(F_G) = F_H$ may fail. What is an example? My feeling is that there must be an extreme example, so a group $G$ with $F_G = 1$ but which surjects onto a nilpotent group $H$, so that $F_H = H$. I suspect that it might work when $G$ is a free group of rank $ > 1$, but I am not sure how to compute $F_G$ in that case.

As to your second question, it is enough to consider the surjective homomorphism from the non-abelian group of order $6$ to the cyclic group of order $2$.

Thank you. Can you please post this an answer (since it is an answer)?

I am posting it as an answer presently - thank you,

I have added a separate answer, in which I address (hopefully correctly) your first question. Please let me know what you think - TIA.

Please do not create new tags without first discussing it with the community.  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35451/

@XanderHenderson Thanks! I proposed it here.

A couple of examples related to the second question.
$S_{3}$ has a Fitting subgroup $A_{3}$ of order $3$, but the quotient $S_{3}/A_{3}$, of order $2$, is its own Fitting subgroup.
For another example, $S_{5}$ has trivial Fitting subgroup, but $S_{5}/A_{5}$, of order $2$, is its own Fitting subgroup.

$\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}$Let me try and address the first question. Consider the following (infinite!) group
\begin{equation*}
G
=
\prod_{i \in \NN} H_{i} \times \prod_{j \in \NN} C_{i},
\end{equation*}
where each $H_{i}$ is isomorphic to $S_{3}$, and each $C_{i}$ is a cyclic group of order $2$. If $K_{i}$ is the subgroup of order $3$ of $H_{i}$, then the Fitting subgroup of $G$ is
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{i \in \NN} K_{i} \times \prod_{j \in \NN} C_{i}.
\end{equation*}
Now consider the quotient $G/K_{0}$. This is clearly isomorphic to $G$ itself, as the copy $H_{0}$ of $S_{3}$ is sent to a copy of the cyclic group of order $2$. Let us fix a specific isomorphism $\psi : G \to G/K_{0}$, which sends $H_{i}$ to $H_{i+1}$, $C_{i}$ to $C_{i-1}$, for $i > 0$, and $C_{0}$ to $H_{0}/K_{0}$.
So there is a surjective homomorphism $\varphi : G \to G$ which is the composition of the natural surjective homomorphism $\pi : G \to G/K_{0}$ and $\psi^{-1}$.
Now note that $\pi$ sends the Fitting subgroup of $G$ to
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{i > 0} K_{i} \times \prod_{j \in \NN} C_{i},
\end{equation*}
which is properly contained in the Fitting subgroup of $G/K_{0}$, which is
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{i > 0} K_{i} \times \color{red}{H_{0}/K_{0}} \times \prod_{j \in \NN} C_{i}.
\end{equation*}
Since $\psi$ and $\psi^{-1}$ are isomorphisms, and thus preserve the Fitting subgroup, one sees that the image of the Fitting subgroup of $G$ under $\varphi$ is properly contained in the Fitting subgroup of $G$.

+1. Ah, so the statement on groupprops is wrong then? Maybe we should fix it.

@MartinBrandenburg, I'm not sure how to fix it - are you planning to do that? - otherwise let me know and I'll try and do it myself.

I am not sure how to get an account there, so I cannot login. Maybe an email to Vipul Naik will also do (who maintains the page, apparently). Please go ahead, since it's your counterexample! :)

@MartinBrandenburg, ok, I'll try and do it.

@MartinBrandenburg in the end I have reported the error via the dedicated page on groupprops.
